# AKS + ACR - Flux gives me err="requesting tags: when I try automatic deployments

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-acr

I'm using AKS with ACR and it works fine when I specify an image (update the Deployment .yaml file manually to update the image version name).

But when I try to do this automatically using image tag filtering:
https://docs.fluxcd.io/en/latest/references/fluxctl/

Using:

```
fluxctl policy `
    --k8s-fwd-ns="flux" `
    --workload=default:deployment/myclient `
    --tag-all="mybranch_*"
```

which adds:

```
fluxcd.io/tag.myclient: glob:mybranch_*
```

When I do:

```
kubectl -n flux logs <podId>
```

I get this error:

```
 err="requesting tags: Get \"https://my_azure_acr/v2/clients/myclient/tags/list\": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have permission to control the ACR. And as it shows [here](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/#azure-container-registry), you need to add a secret to authenticate to the ACR for Flux.